# WebSocket with Django and Expo not working

Tags: javascript, django, react-native, websocket, expo

I am building an expo app that uses Django for backend. For the app I need to use WebSocket. But when I try to connect to the WebSocket on my Django project, I get

```
Not Found: /ws/
[25/Sep/2023 19:34:58] "GET /ws/ HTTP/1.1" 404 2678
```

This is my Expo code:

```
const socket = React.useRef(new WebSocket('ws://myIP:8000/ws/')).current;
    console.log(socket) 
    if (socket) {
        // Now you can safely work with the WebSocket object 
      } else {
        console.error('WebSocket is undefined.');
    }
    socket.onmessage = (event) => {
        console.log(event.data)
        // Handle incoming messages from the WebSocket server
      };
        
      socket.onopen = () => {
        // WebSocket connection opened 
        console.log("opened")
      };
      
      socket.onclose = (event) => {
        // WebSocket connection closed
      };
      
      socket.onerror = (error) => {
        // Handle WebSocket errors
        console.log("error")
      };
```

This is my Django code:

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'home',
    'channels',
]

ASGI_APPLICATION = 'API.routing.application'
```

routing.py

```
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
from django.urls import path
from .consumers import YourWebSocketConsumer
from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "API.settings")

application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    "http": get_asgi_application(),
    "websocket": URLRouter(
        [
            path("ws/", YourWebSocketConsumer.as_asgi()),
            # Add more WebSocket consumers and paths as needed
        ]
    ),
})
```

consumers.py

```
from channels.generic.websocket import AsyncWebsocketConsumer
import json

class YourWebSocketConsumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):
    async def connect(self):
        await self.accept()

    async def disconnect(self, close_code):
        pass

    async def receive(self, text_data):
        data = json.loads(text_data)
        message = data['message']

        # Process the received message
        # You can send a response back to the client using self.send()

        await self.send(text_data=json.dumps({'message': 'Response to your message'}))
```

Implementing WebSocket is essential for my application's functionality. How can I fix this so I could make the WebSocket work?

*Found out that the code works when I use a different computer. Is there something I need to install in order to make this work?

Comment: the route `/ws` is interpreted as `http` rather than as `ws` protocol. you need to make exception to the http rule so that route `/ws` will not be processed as http.  maybe handle the `/ws` first, then all other https.

Comment: Thank you for your response. How can I implement that?

Comment: Found out that the code works when I use a different computer. Is there something I need to install in order to make this work?

Comment: maybe firewall for port 8000, or something in the environment config . for the browser no need to install anyhing